# How to report my repeated measures analysis?

Tags: anova, mixed-model, repeated-measures, reporting, two-way

I've conducted an experiment with 30 participants using a counterbalanced design they performed a task in two slightly different conditions. After both conditions participants were asked to fill in a questionnaire to measure mental workload and their performance times were recorded.

The data was analyzed by performing two repeated measures. One for each dependent variable (mental workload and performance). The conditions were set to create a within subjects variable and the sequence of conditions was added as a between subjects factor (to control for cross learning effects).

The output shows both multivariate tests and within subjects tests (but no differences between the p-values). I am unsure if this constitues two two-way ANOVA's or whether it is a mixed anova. All participants were subject to both conditions but the between-subject variable (i.e. sequence)does split them into two groups.
My question is which results to report and how I should phrase my analysis.

Thank you